# How to find the pressure force on a solid body

Tags: calculus, fluid-dynamics

> Calculate the pressure force, or drag (per unit length), on an (infinite) circular cylinder of radius $a$ due to a uniform stream of speed $U_0$ of an
>   incompressible, irrotational fluid flowing past it.

I have that
$$\underline{u} = u_r\underline{\hat{R}} + v_\theta\underline{\hat{\phi}} = \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial R}\underline{\hat{R}} + \frac{1}{R}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \phi}\underline{\hat{\phi}}$$
Where $R=a$, $\underline{\hat{n}} = \underline{\hat{R}}$, the following must satisfy: $\underline{u}\cdot\underline{\hat{n}} = 0$.
$$\underline{u}\cdot\underline{\hat{n}} = u_R = \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial R} = 0 \Rightarrow \Psi = 0\quad \text{at}\quad R=a$$
But I am completely lost after this. How is a problem like this done?

Comment: I think this question belongs on [Physics stack exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: no why does everyone say that? on physics they say they don't help with calculation. this is apart of my mathematics course

Comment: Perhaps cus fluid dynamics , pressure etc are a part of physics .Idk

Comment: Is $\hat{\underline\phi}$ meant to be $\hat{\underline\theta}$?

Comment: Also, what are $\Phi$ and $\Psi$?

Comment: @CheeHan: $\underline{\hat{\phi}}$ could be $\underline{\hat{\theta}}$. It is the angle that goes aroung the cross section from $0$ to $2\pi$. $\Phi$ is the potential in my notes and $\Psi$ is the Stokes's streamfunction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the origin of the coordinate system at the center of the circular cross-section of the cylinder. With a uniform stream away from the cylinder, the velocity field and potential $\Phi$ is symmetric with respect to reflection across the $x-$ axis, i.e. $\Phi(x,y) = \Phi(x,-y)$.  We also have fore-aft symmetry and $\Phi(x,y) = \Phi(-x,y).$

From Bernoulli's equation, $\frac{p}{\rho} = \text{const.} - \frac{1}{2}\left|\nabla \Phi \right|^2$, we see that the pressure at the surface of the cylinder has the same symmetry property.

Let $C = C_1 \cup C_2$ be the circular contour of the cylinder where $C_1$ is the upper half where $y > 0$ and $C_2$ is the lower half where $y < 0$. The drag force per unit length is obtained by integrating $-p \,\mathbb{n}$ around the $C$ to obtain

$$\mathbf{F} = -\int_Cp \,\mathbf{n}\,dl = - \int_{C_1}p \,\mathbf{n}\,dl - \int_{C_2}p \,\mathbf{n}\,dl . $$

Since $p(x,y) = p(x,-y)$ and $\mathbf{n}(x,y)\cdot \mathbf{j} = - \mathbf{n}(x,-y)\cdot \mathbf{j}$, the contributions from $C_1$ and $C_2$ cancel and we have

$$\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{0}.$$

Here we have D'Alembert's paradox which states that in steady, two-dimensional, potential flow, the net force on a body is zero. It is particularly easy to prove, as in this case,  where the body is symmetric and placed in a unidirectional streaming flow.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the drag force per unit length is given by the $\int_C \underline{\underline{\sigma}}\cdot\mathbf{n}\, d\ell$, where $\underline{\underline{\sigma}}$ is the stress tensor on the circular cylinder $r=a$?

Comment: @CheeHan: Yes, in general, but for potential flow there is no viscous stress .  OP stated irrotational flow so I am assuming inviscid.  If we had viscous flow past a cylinder then it would not be irrotational and of course there is no exact solution except for $ Re = 0, \infty$.  The later is the inviscid limit.

Comment: Why viscous flow implies rotational?

Comment: (1) In the full Navier-Stokes solution with no-slip condition at the cylinder surface, vorticity is generated at the surface and diffuses outward. (2) The flow is incompressible and irrotational so $\nabla^2 \boldsymbol u = \nabla(\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol u)-\nabla\times(\nabla\times \boldsymbol u) = \boldsymbol 0$ and all viscous effects are negligible. (3) In irrotational flow the velocity must be the gradient of a potential and trying to specify both zero normal and tangential velocity at the surface is ill-posed. (4) The OP could not answer such a question if we have full Navier-Stokes.

Comment: Ahhhh yes. Thanks!

Comment: @RRl: Yes I thought that I should get D'Alembert's theorem but I wasn't sure how to deal with the cylinder being infinite. I was very confused but thank you for taking the time to provide a detailed solution.

Comment: @MRT: You're welcome.